# Is there a way to tell Visual Studio to show certain member values by default while in debug mode?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, .net-4.0, visual-studio-2013

Certain .NET classes must have some kind of attribute set on either the class or individual members to tell it to show those members' values by default while hovering the mouse over an object in debug mode.  Here's an example:

[image]

Out of all the members in `Type`, only `Name` and `FullName` are shown while the object is fully collapsed.  I'd like to do the same for some of my own classes so that I can have an entity's ID and Name members shown by default.  Is there a way I can do this?

Note:  My question pertains to VS 2013, but it would be nice to know how to do this for earlier versions like 2010 or earlier for those using older versions.  I am also using C# 4.0 just in case the method to achieve what I am doing differs between languages and .NET frameworks.

Comment: For your own types you could use a custom `ToString` implementation that would be used there. But that's surely not the answer here.

Comment: [Debugger Display Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228992.aspx)

Comment: See also: [How do I change the output in the debugger for a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6946640)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the [DebuggerDisplayAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.diagnostics.debuggerdisplayattribute.aspx)

You can use it in your classes like

```
[DebuggerDisplay("Name = {Name}, Id = {Id}")]
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Upvoted. But you should mention that in the absense of a `DebuggerDisplayAttribute`, the `ToString()` override is used. So if that string representation is useful more generally (not only during debugging), one could override `ToString()` instead.

Comment: Nice!  Even though it turns out to be a dupe question, I'll keep it around to make it easier to find since this is one of those rare questions where you have to know the answer in order to ask the right question.